# Can 1/2 drive impact wrenches be adapted to use 3/8 sockets?

Tags: tools, stuck-bolt, fastener

I need to add a cordless impact wrench to my toolset do some exhaust work (loosen some really tight bolts, basically). I also plant to use it for CV joint-related work.

They seem to be kind of pricey, so I can only get either a 1/2" or 3/8" drive right now. Which is more versatile?

If I get the 1/2" one, are there any adapters like in regular hand ratchets to downgrade from 1/2" to 3/8"? Or are these impact guns fixed and you must have both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1/2"-drive can withstand more torque than its 3/8" sibling (due to its larger moment of area). Since the question clearly states that this is needed to undo really tight or stuck bolts, the 1/2"-drive impact wrench makes more sense.

As for recommendations, there will always be someone recommending Brand A over Brand B and vice versa. That said, I'm looking to pick up something like the one in [this video](https://youtu.be/yR32-z5s7aU) if the price is right.

Answer (score 3):

I have only ever had/used 1/2" drive air impact guns. The reason is simple: I can produce as much/more torque with a 1/2" breaker bar than a 3/8" impact drive can produce. If I need to use an impact wrench (which usually works *really* well on rusty bolts), I'll grab the 1/2" drive and have at it. For me, there usually is no reason for a 3/8" impact drive, so why have/use one.

As for electric impact drives, I understand the newer battery operated ones are very nice to have. I believe most of these are 3/8" drive. For this reason alone, I may have change of heart. Having to not haul a hose around plus the ability to remotely carry it to where I need it would be a great bonus.

Answer (score 3):

1/2" drive is the way to go, the only advantage to the 3/8" is it's going to be smaller and lighter. With the major disadvantage of much less torque.

> are there any adapters like in regular hand ratchets to downgrade from 1/2" to 3/8"?

Yes.

1/2" to 3/8" adapters are readily available on all the tool trucks, and most other places that sell tools.

Here's a few examples, not only are the readily available they make them for impact wrenches.

[Snap on Adaptor, 3/8" Internal drive x 1/2" External drive, 1 5/16"](https://store.snapon.com/Square-Drive-Adaptors-chrome-Adaptor-3-8-Internal-drive-x-1-2-External-drive-1-5-16--P631531.aspx)

[Bottom right of this page in the Snap on Catolog](http://bluetoad.com/publication/?i=106395#%7B%22issue_id%22:106395,%22page%22:84%7D)

Again this one is made to be used with an impact wrench.

The ones pictured below are NOT for impact wrenches

[image]

[Craftsman  4 pc. Adapter Set](http://www.craftsman.com/craftsman-4-pc-adapter-set/p-00904235000P)

While this one is for use with impact wrenches.

[image]

[Craftsman  1/2 in. to 3/8 in. Impact Socket Adapter](http://www.craftsman.com/craftsman-1-2-in-to-3-8-in-impact-socket/p-00919494000P)

It's is **important** that you use impact sockets as **non-impact sockets can shatter when used on an impact wrench**.